# How to format lines in a file by using shell language?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

The purpose of the program is to make comments in the file begin in the same column.
if a line begins with ; then it doesn't change
if a line begins with code then ;  the program should insert space before ; so it will start in the same column with the farthest ;

for example:

Before:

```
; Also change "-f elf " for "-f elf64" in build command. 
; 
section .data                    ; section for initialized data 
str: db 'Hello world!', 0Ah                   ; message string with new-line char 
                               ; at the end (10 decimal)
```

After：

```
; Also change "-f elf " for "-f elf64" in build command.                # These two line don't change 
;                                                                       # because they start with ;
section .data                                 ; section for initialized data     
str: db 'Hello world!', 0Ah                   ; message string with new-line char
                                              ; at the end (10 decimal)
```

I am a beginner in Linux and shell, so far I have got

```
echo "Enter the filename"
read name

cat $name | while read line;
do ....
```

Our teacher told us that we should use two while loop;
Record the longest length before; in the first loop and do the changes in the second while loop.
for now I don't know how to use awk or sed to find the longest length before;

Any ideas?

Comment: A couple. Set `IFS=$';\n'` to only break on `;` or `newline`. Don't `cat $foo | while...` use `while ... done <"$foo"`, or putting it all together `while IFS=$';\n' read code comment; do ...test code...test comment...printf "%*s %s\n" "$width" "$code" "$comment" done <"$foo"`. That will help move the ball along. There may be other tricks if you get stuck.

Comment: Can your strings contain semi-colons? e.g. `str: db 'Hello; world!', 0Ah`? If so how can we tell when a semi-colon is the start of a comment vs part of a string or some other non-comment context?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, assuming that comments in your file begin with the first semi-colon (`;`) **that is not inside a string**:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
{
    nostrings = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/'[^']*'/) ) {
        nostrings = nostrings substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%*s",RLENGTH,"")
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    nostrings = nostrings tail
    cur = index(nostrings,";")
}
NR==FNR { max = (cur > max ? cur : max); next }
cur > 1 { $0 = sprintf("%-*s%s", max-1, substr($0,1,cur-1), substr($0,cur)) }
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
; Also change "-f elf " for "-f elf64" in build command.
;
section .data                                  ; section for initialized data
str: db 'Hello; world!', 0Ah                   ; message string with new-line char
                                               ; at the end (10 decimal)
```

and below is how you get to it from a naive starting point (I added a semi-colon inside your `Hello World!` string for testing - make sure to verify all suggested solutions using that).

Note that the above DOES contain 2 loops on the input as your teacher suggests, but you do not need to manually write them as awk provides the loops for you each time it reads the file. If your input file contains tabs or similar then you need to remove them in advance, e.g. by using `pr -e -t`.

Here is how you get to the above:

If you cannot have semi-colons in other contexts than as the start of comments then all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ cur = index($0,";") }
NR==FNR { max = (cur > max ? cur : max); next }
cur > 1 { $0 = sprintf("%-*s%s", max-1, substr($0,1,cur-1), substr($0,cur)) }
{ print }
```

which you'd execute as `awk -f tst.awk file file` (yes, specify your input file twice).

If your code can contain semi-colons in contexts that are not the start of a comment, e.g. in the middle of a string, then you need to tell us how we can identify semi-colons in comment-start vs other contexts but if it can ONLY appear between singe quotes in strings, e.g. the `;` inside `'Hello; World!'` below:

```
$ cat file
; Also change "-f elf " for "-f elf64" in build command.
;
section .data                    ; section for initialized data
str: db 'Hello; world!', 0Ah                   ; message string with new-line char
                               ; at the end (10 decimal)
```

then this is all you need to replace every string with a series of blank chars before finding the first semi-colon (which is then presumably the start of a comment):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    nostrings = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/'[^']*'/) ) {
        nostrings = nostrings substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%*s",RLENGTH,"")
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    nostrings = nostrings tail
    cur = index(nostrings,";")
}
...the rest as before...
```

and finally if you don't want to specify the file name twice on the command line, just duplicate it's name in the ARGV[] array by adding this line at the top:

```
BEGIN{ ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
```

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, use a while loop to find the longest length, given your input in the local file `input`:

```
length=0
length2=0
while IFS= read -r -- i; do
(( ${#i} > length2 )) && length2=${#i}
i=${i/\;*/}
(( ${#i} > length )) && length=${#i}
done < ./input
(( length++ )); (( length2++ ))
```

In your next while loop, detect whether the line starts with `;` using `[[ ${i:0:1} = ';' ]]` and output it, or format the output with awk using the length you determined: `awk -F\; -v len=$length '{ printf "%-"len"s %-40s\n", $1, $2}'`. Check here (http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/117543-formatting-output-columns.html) for more info on column formatting.

Edit: In case you didn't figure it out, the second loop looks like:

```
while IFS= read -r -- i; do
# echo the original if the line starts with ';'
[[ ${i:0:1} = ';' ]] && echo "$i" && continue
# column formatting with awk
(echo "$i" | grep -q ';') && echo "$i" | awk -v len=$length -v len2=$length2 -F\; '{printf "%-"len"s %-"len2"s\n",$1,";"$2}' || echo "$i"
done < ./input
```

That will give you what you want for the output.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few `printf` tricks that make this a manageable project. Take a look at the following. The script formats the assembly file with the assembly code beginning at column `0` to `code_width - 1` with the comments following at column `code_width` lined up after the code. The script is fairly well commented so you should be able to follow along.

The usage is:

```
bash nameofscript.sh input_file [code_width (default 46char)]
```

or if you make `nameofscript.sh` `executable`, then simply:

```
./nameofscript.sh input_file [code_width (default 46char)]
```

**NOTE:** this script requires **Bash**, if not run on bash, you may experience inconsistent results. If you have multiple embedded `;` in each line, the first will be considered the beginning of a comment. Let me know if you have questions.

```
#!/bin/bash

## basic function to trim (or stip) the leading & trailing whitespace from a variable
#  passed to the fuction. Usage: VAR=$(trimws $VAR)
function trimws {
    [ -z "$1" ] && return 1
    local strln="${#1}"
    [ "$strln" -lt 2 ] && return 1
    local trimstr=$1
    trimstr="${trimstr#"${trimstr%%[![:space:]]*}"}"  # remove leading whitespace characters
    trimstr="${trimstr%"${trimstr##*[![:space:]]}"}"  # remove trailing whitespace characters
    printf "%s" "$trimstr"
    return 0
}

afn="$1"                        # input assembly filename
cwidth=${2:--46}                # code field width (- is left justified)

[ "${cwidth:0:1}" = '-' ] || cwidth=-${cwidth}  # make sure first char is '-'

[ -r "$afn" ] || {              # validate input file is readable
    printf "error: file not found: '%s'. Usage: %s <filename> [code_width (46 ch)]\n" "$afn" "${0//\//}"
    exit 1
}

## loop through file splitting on ';'
while IFS=$';\n' read -r code comment || [ -n "$comment" ]; do

    [ -n "$code" ] || {                 # if no '$code' comment only line
        if [ -n "$comment" ]; then
            printf ";%s\n" "$comment"   # output the line unchanged
        else
            printf "\n"                 # it was a blank line to begin with
        fi
        continue                        # read next line
    }
    code=$(trimws "$code")              # trim leading and trailing whitespace
    comment=$(trimws "$comment")        # same
    printf "%*s ; %s\n" "$cwidth" "$code" "$comment"    # output new format

done <"$afn"

exit 0
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/asmfile.txt
; Also change "-f elf " for "-f elf64" in build command.
;
section .data                    ; section for initialized data
str: db 'Hello world!', 0Ah                   ; message string with new-line char
                               ; at the end (10 decimal)
```

**output:**

```
$ bash fmtasmcmt.sh
; Also change "-f elf " for "-f elf64" in build command.
;
section .data                                  ; section for initialized data
str: db 'Hello world!', 0Ah                    ; message string with new-line char
                                               ; at the end (10 decimal)
```

Comment: Ed, the title looks like a red herring. It is tagged `Linux` `bash` etc.. I considered your earlier comment and decided to let the OP provide feedback if there were issues. I think this is exactly what he needed. He is just trying to line up comments in assembly files.

Comment: Fair enough, did the OP just tag it as `Bash` by accident? We are both making assumptions here. The code I posted meets `Bash` perfectly. You are arguing that the mutually exclusive parts of the `shell` tag could cause issues. I get that. Neither of us know for sure. Why SO allows both `Bash` and `shell` at the same time with the inherent mutually exclusive code it `Bash` is beyond me. I'll drop a NOTE that the code is for bash. That is the best either of us can do.

Comment: I think if you compare his recommendations of the safe way to approach it `quoting`, `printf`, etc.. you will find each of those contained in my code. I didn't code it by accident. If you look at the particular care taken in the `trimws` code, I trim each and every string down to an exact minimum to insure there are no `gotchas`.

Comment: Now we are down to the nuts and bolts. This we don't have to speculate about -- fixed.

Comment: We can agree to disagree. I disabled nothing and in fact used many of the facilities mentioned in your link. Yes, I read it fully. There is no magic there, just the opinion of one guy that happens to like to spawn subshells using 3rd party utilities instead of using what bash provides. For every Chazelas, I've found another that thinks differently, just as experienced. There is more than one way to skin a cat -- and that's a good thing.

Comment: For the OP - do not use shell loops to process text, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and google Stéphane Chazelas.

Comment: David - the link I reference provides a detailed description of the negatives of using shell loops to manipulate text written by one of the worlds leading shell experts and discoverer of the ShellShock bug. Could you tell us (or provide a similar reference for) the positives of using shell loops to manipulate text? I am open to learning if I have been misinformed.

Comment: Ed, and here is a line where Stephane explains [**Howto read file line-by-line in bash**](http://dbaspot.com/shell/381104-howto-read-file-line-line-bash.html). You are taking as absolute something that is **not** and absolute and using it to libel my code -- something I, nor anyone else, would appreciate.

Comment: David - the answer you reference describes "**HOW** to do it" if you have to, not "**SHOULD** you do it" and specifically says `The nicest way is to avoid while read loops in shells.`. I am in no way libeling your code - you clearly put a lot of effort into it and if the OP needs to use shell builtins to do the job then maybe your script would be appropriate but the OP deserves to know that there are far better ways to solve the problem using standard UNIX commands and there are a lot of non-obvious issues with using a shell loop to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to use this example for my personal formatting!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s -0
use strict;
our ($com);                          # command line option
$com = ";"  unless defined $com  ;

my $max=0;        
$_= <>;                                     # slurp file

while( /\n(.+?)$com/g ){ 
        $max=length($1) if length($1) > $max }

s/\n(.+?)$com/sprintf("\n%-$max"."s$com",$1)/ge;
print $_;                              # print file
```

- usage: `align_coms input`    (after chmod+install)
- Options: `-com=...`  to redefine comments (default = ; )

and you can try `align_coms -com=# align_coms` to align this scripts perl comments :)

**Edit 1:**
Please see the (wise) comment of @EdMorton about problems when the input has strings (or similar) containing  comment starters.

**Edit 2:** The following version can deal with 'alo; word' "alo; word". It is still
**not safe** -- real languages have always some extra detail (ex '...\'...', multiline comments) but it is a little bit more robust...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s -0
use strict;
our ($com);                          # command line option
$com = ";"  unless defined $com  ;

my $nc=qr{                           # no comment regex
           (   '[^'\n]*'             # '....'
             | "[^"\n]*"             # "...."
             | .                     # common chars
           )+?
         }x;                        

my $max=0;
$_= <>;                              # slurp file

while( /\n($nc)$com/g ){
        $max=length($1) if length($1) > $max }

s/\n($nc)$com/sprintf("\n%-$max"."s$com",$1)/ge;
print $_;                            # print file
```

Comment: what would it do if your script contained a comment-start character inside a string or a regexp? For example if I ran it as `align_coms -com=# script` and `script` contained a line like `$com = "#"` (or whatever the correct perl syntax is to set a variable named `com` to be a string containing a `#` character).

Comment: **Very good point**! At the moment I'm using this (a more complex version of this) in VIM: I programmed a vim key to do align_coms block. We can
reduce the problem of strings with more complex regex (Ex `("[^"]*"|[^\n#"])+`) but it is impossible to cover all the perl triks (awk, C, to, I
believe) with simple regex. In short: this kind of scrips may help  but **they are not safe**!